# When to take logarithms of a variable such as the Herfindahl Index?

Tags: logistic, data-transformation, linear-model, link-function

Currently I am skimming through a couple of papers in well established journals! 
I became curious when I found papers with linear regression models using the Herfindahl index as the dependent variable. I thought such a continuous but limited variable had to be used in combination with the ln!

Could any of you give me an explanation whether one procedure is right or wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are presuming familiarity with the Herfindahl index, which is close to assuming that the readers of this forum are all some kind of applied economist, modulo a few eclectics and polymaths. However, the crucial information here is that the Herfindahl index (which in essence was discovered by Gini, decades earlier, hence its name) is a measure that must be positive and cannot exceed 1.

That being so, its logarithm will be negative or zero and cannot be positive. Thus even in principle taking the logarithm cannot solve the problem that this index is a limited measure, because it merely replaces one bound by another. As with many limited measures leaving the variable untransformed might be considered adequate so long as no predicted values from a regression violated the bounds. However, I suspect that there is a stronger case for working on logit scale (or with a logit link if there are values exactly 1) for reasons concisely and lucidly reviewed in

Baum, C.F. 2008. Modeling proportions. *Stata Journal* 8(2): 299-303.                                  accessible at http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0147

Some references from your literature search might help any people looking at this in future.

Comment: There's a version of HHI that uses whole percentages, so the index range is $(0,100^2]$.

Comment: @Dimitriy Fine; same point applies.